# Probabilites, Statistics and Counting Questions

Tags: probability, statistics, gre-exam

I'm practicing some GRE math problems which I don't have answers for. Would you please correct my answers if they're wrong?

**Q1.**

You have 4 books, A and B and C and D. In how many ways you can arrange them on a shelf and keep book A and book C next to each other?

**A.**

2*1*2*1 = 4

**Q2.**

Anne closet contain 11 pants, 4 of them are blue. 7 hats, 3 of them are blue. 8 shirts, 2 of them are blue. What's the probability that Anne would grab a blue pants, a blue hat and a blue shirt?

**A.**

1/4 * 1/3 * 1/2 = 1/24

**Q3.**

A set of 7 different integers, it's range is 12, and it's median is 86. What's the lease possible of the first integer in the set?

**A.**

integers after median in the set would be: {,,,86,87,88,89} and 89-12=77 So answer is 77.

Comment: The answer to Q1 is not right. Imagine book A and book C as one big book F. In how many ways you can arrange B,D and F ? Additionally you have to consider, that A and C can be arranged in two ways.

Comment: For Q2, consider the probability that she picked a blue pair of pants ($\frac{4}{11}$), the probability that she picked a blue hat ($\frac{3}{7}$), and the probability she picked a blue shirt ($\frac{2}{8}$).  It seems safe to assume a uniform probability distribution for each and that they are independent, so to find the probability of all happening, you multiply the probabilities for $\frac{4}{11}\cdot\frac{3}{7}\cdot\frac{2}{8}$.  (I had a typo in my earlier comment, caught by @calculus)

Comment: @calculus i see. so it would be 3*2*1*2 ? or 3*2*1? Thanks!

Comment: @JMoravitz Many thanks!

Comment: @Shadin The first one is right. B,D,F can be arranged in $3!=1*2*3=6$ ways. And A and C can be arranged in 2 ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Consider 'AC' as a single object. There are 3! ways in which to arrange three objects 'AC', B and D. Then multiply by 2 because
A and C are still next to each other if it's 'CA'. Answer: 12 ways.

```
 ACBD  ACDB  BACD  DACB  BDAC  DBAC
 CABD  CADB  BCAD  DCAB  BDCA  DBCA
```

(2) Answered in Comment by @JMoravitz

(3) "77, two intermediate digits, 86, two intermediate digits, 89"
has 7 digits, median 86, range 89 - 77 = 12, and s0 satisfies the
requirements.

But if the integers didn't need to be DIFFERENT, we could have
"75, 77, 79, 86, 87, 87, 87" for a smaller minimum number.

Comment: Wishing you a magnificent score on the GRE.